# Knockoutjs - access collection of data

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have json collection like this

```
0: {type:1, 
    checkboxVal: 1, 
    SelectedDropdown1Val: 19, 
    SelectedDropdown2Val: 14, 
    SelectedDropdown3Val: 1, …}

1: {type:2, 
    checkboxVal: 0, 
    SelectedDropdown1Val: 0, 
    SelectedDropdown2Val: 14, 
    SelectedDropdown3Val: 2,…}
```

Each line of `json` data need to display into diff view instead of display into `HTML` table. The views will look like this

`checkbox1 | Dropdown1`            --> This line need get data from `json` line 0 and this line might not exist.

`checkbox2 | Dropdown2 | Dropdown3`--> This line need get data from `json` line 1 and this line might not exist.

So how do i using knockout to access the data to populate into my above view? Any advise?

This is the, http://jsfiddle.net/tsohtan/evGy8/1/, html that i would like to populate data with knockoutjs but i don want to use foreach to populate into the element ? is that possible to achieve?

Comment: This sample doesn't show what you have tried if anything. Have you looked at using observable arrays and performing a foreach on it? If so, post more code, if not, I'd start there and update your question with specific issues you come across.

Comment: @Tanner: i trying to figure out how to use knockoutjs in my project, and i try to understand from this sample http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/. So i don't have any HTML and i've no idea on how to access the viewmodel if without using foreach. As i'm not display into HTML table. I need to display into different HTML element instead of HTML table.

Comment: @Tanner, i think i come out simple HTML later to ease your guys to help me. Sorry. Will post it later.

Comment: @Tanner included the html as above. or here http://jsfiddle.net/tsohtan/evGy8/1/

Comment: Even with the fiddle, I still don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want a simple example of binding a select list with knockout, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/nX4xj/, perhaps use this as a base to explain your issue as it's a working example.